# Trying to target specific DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, html, click, target

Simple problem with what seems to be an incredibly difficult solution.

I have a DIV wrapper with a z-index that is lower than a DIV that is inside the wrapper. (basically a background with a DIV on top of it)

When I run the console.log() on the wrapper, and the DIV, I notice that when I click on the wrapper it only logs the click for the wrapper.

But when I click on the DIV inside the wrapper, it logs clicks for both the wrapper and the DIV at the same time.

How the heck do I set this up so that when I click on the DIV inside the wrapper, it will only register a click for that DIV and not the wrapper as well??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Jeff's answer, here's some basic sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {width:100px;height:100px;}
    #parent {padding:50px;background-color:black}
    #child {background-color:yellow}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('div').click(function (event) {
            if ($(this).parents('div')) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this solution does solve the issue, it kills all clicks on on my wrapper DIV.

Basically I want only the child DIV to register the click for that DIV when you click on it, and only want the parent DIV to register a click when I click on the parent. 

This solution kills click recognition of the wrapper DIV

Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I had it in the wrong place.

THANKS AGAIN FOR YOU HELP! MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: @Alex: Yeah, you will definitely want to narrow down your selectors.  It's almost never a good idea to use `div` as a selector, but for this basic scenario it seemed relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use stopPropagation.  See this for more info:

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)